# Can't add app in iTunesConnect

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect

I want to add my new app in iTunesConnect. When I click on plus, I get this warning:

[image]

According to this text I click on Member Center link, but I see there nothing:
[image]

In result I can't add my new app in any case( How this problem may be solved? I have a warn there, that my membership will be closed soon, today I've sent 99$, so everything will be ok, but I can't add any app to publish.

Comment: It takes time for the data to be updated.

Comment: @KosukeOgawa Which data? My new payment? Then everything should be ok?